# Outputting specific lines of curl output

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.6

I would like to display only certain lines of curl output (example, lines 15-20). I know how to output only 1 line if I write output to a txt file.  But how to do this without outputting to text first? And how so I select multiple lines?

If $myFile = "/whatever.txt" , this works for just line 22. But not using curl variable.

Thank you.

```
<?php
$handle = curl_init();
$url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/";
// Set the url
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set the result output to be a string.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
//echo $output;
$myFile = "$output";
$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array
echo $lines[22]; // displays line 23 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: You can use the explode function, using `\n` as separator. Then you could get the desired lines by their index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not getting any data from google finance as it is ssl protected. Hence you have to add the necessary ssl options to curl to get the text. See the corrected code.

```
$handle = curl_init();
$url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/";
// Set the url
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set the result output to be a string.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$output=curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$myFile = "myfile.txt";
file_put_contents($myFile,$output);

$lines = file($myFile);//file in to an array


echo $lines[114]; // displays line 114 which has some text
```

Comment: Excellent, I understand now!